# Can't get Another field from session

Tags: codeigniter, session

I got problem about session data, in my web, i want to make a different view based on previledge user, here my code in controller :

```
    $previledge = $this->session->userdata['previledge'];
    $data['previledge']=$previledge;
    if($data['previledge'] == 'admin'){
                $this->load->view("app_admin/global/header",$d);
                $this->load->view("app_admin/materi/home");
                $this->load->view("app_admin/global/footer");
    }
    else {
                $this->load->view("app_admin/global/header2",$d);
                $this->load->view("app_admin/materi/home");
                $this->load->view("app_admin/global/footer");
    }

    }
```

if i run my code above, previledge with admin can't go to the right view.
if there any suggestion, please inform,
thanks

Comment: please check $data coming in the session  you will get the idea what needs to be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its something like syntax error.

```
$previledge = $this->session->userdata('previledge');
```

This will help you.

Comment: do `var_dump($this->session->userdata())` and check you are getting data of `previledge` in session or not

Comment: do `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())`

Answer (score 1):

Below code must have to work

```
$this->session->userdata('previledge')=='admin'
```

Comment: once print session data and then check whether it is correct or not